# Cant Workout Why this C Condition Fails

Tags: c

I have a problem with some C code I am writing as part of a University assignment.  Consider the code:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
if ((argv[1] == "--verbose") || (argv[1] == "-v")) {
  printf("%d\n", argc);
}
```

now:  `printf("%s\n", argv[1]);` prints "--verbose" so I know `argv[1] == "--verbose"` should be true, but the line `printf("%d\n", argc);` never executes.  And I cant workout why.  Any ideas?

Comment: Using `==` in that way compares the *locations* of the strings, not their contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`strcmp`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) function:

```
strcmp(argv[1], "--verbose") == 0
```

`==` checks that two pointers have the same address, which is not what you want.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a tonne.  And thanks for the clear and concise answer.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [Wikipedia Article on `strcmp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcmp).

Key here is you cannot compare strings directly with the `==` operator in C. This will only compare the pointers to the strings, which will be different.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't compare strings with == in C. Use strcmp or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using `strcmp` to compare strings?  Surely `argv[1] == "--verbose"` will not compare for equality of the strings to the letter.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are actually comparing the contents of the `argv[1]` pointer (which points to the string containing the first argument of your program) with the address of each string literal ("-v" etc). This is guaranteed to be false in all cases.

You should use the `strcmp()` function or similar to compare the strings themselves, rather than their addresses.